# Terraform aks module - get cluster name and resource group name via remote state

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Hi I am trying to follow [this offical guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/kubernetes-provider) to manage aks resources. There [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote-state-data.html) is used to get the `resource_group_name` and `kubernetes_cluster_name`.

```golang
data "terraform_remote_state" "aks" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "/path/to/base/project/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

# Retrieve AKS cluster information
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
  name                = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.kubernetes_cluster_name
  resource_group_name = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.resource_group_name
}
```

I have created the inital aks cluster with the [aks module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest). Looking at its [output](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest?tab=outputs) in the documentation, it doesnt export the resource group name or cluster name.

Now I wonder how I can get the information. I have tried the below in the base project.

```golang
module "aks" {
  ...
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = module.aks.resource_group_name
}

output "kubernetes_cluster_name" {
  value = module.aks.cluster_name
}
```

But I get erros when trying `terraform plan`

```sh
Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 59, in output "resource_group_name":
│   59:   value = module.aks.resource_group_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.aks is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "resource_group_name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 63, in output "kubernetes_cluster_name":
│   63:   value = module.aks.cluster_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.aks is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "cluster_name".
```

Those are listed under [inputs](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest?tab=inputs) for that module though. Now I dont have an idea know how to get those values from the `terraform_remote_state`.

Comment: What you could do is to set the `name` and the `resource_group_name` in the `data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster"` to the same values of the variables you provided to the module.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did as workaround. But at least the cluster name is actually optional, so sometimes we dont know it before it was created. Then getting it as output would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I am not a big fan of Azure documentation, I am never sure what is there and what is not. :)

Comment: Hello @TheFool, you can try adding the output.tf in the module first as its not declared there . you can refer this image : https://i.imgur.com/oKT6Tl8.png then you can try calling the output while deploying the aks module please refer this image : https://i.imgur.com/XGQOBEL.png

Comment: Please let me know if it works and if that is what you are looking for .

Comment: Aah now I get it. You add this yourself to the aks module. Correct? Wouldnt this be overwritten on update? Its still really cool in some way. Nice one!

Comment: yeah it will be overwritten during update .. so we have to declare it after doing terraform init.. I will post this as an answer as well..

Comment: Given the simplicity of the implementation, why wasn't it added by default. Maybe you should make a pull request ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the module itself doesn’t have name and resource group as output , we have to declare outputs there first and then call it while deploying or in remote state as well.

So we have to add 2 outputs in output.tf for aks module after doing terraform init.

```
output "kubernetes_cluster_name" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.name
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.resource_group_name
}
```

[image]

Then call outputs in main.tf after defining the modules i.e. network and aks , you can see your Kubernetes cluster name in plan as well and after applying it.

```
output "kuberneteclustername" {
  value = module.aks.kubernetes_cluster_name
}

output "resourcegroupname" {
  value = module.aks.resource_group_name
}
```

[image]

[image]

Now lets test it from the remote state :

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "aks" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "path/to/terraform/aksmodule/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

# Retrieve AKS cluster information
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
  name                = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.kuberneteclustername
  resource_group_name = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.resourcegroupname
}

output "aks" {
  value = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.name
}
output "rg" {
  value = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.resource_group_name
}
```

[image]

Comment: Resource group seems to be available though. I found it in the output under `node_resource_group`. They are taking it the same way you do, so it must be the same. `output "node_resource_group" {value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.node_resource_group}
`

Comment: Yeah resource group seems to be available as node_resource_group as well.. and there can be couple of other methods to get the resource group like output of azurem_resource_group.example.name etc.

Comment: I just simply called them from azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main..

Comment: Its also kind of silly that resource group is available but not the cluster name. Because resource group is required argument to use the module, so it must be known at that point. No need to get it as output actually. The cluster name on the other hand is optional, so there it would make actually sense to set it as output.

Comment: Oh true, yours is not the same. Are the scenarios where the node resource group is different than the cluster resource group?

Comment: Yeah ,I guess they have provided the module and we should modify it as per our requirement .. and no both the resource group are same as we have given one resource group only as parameter

Comment: will accept it although its really not a clean solution. Just because it will overwrite on init